Least risky server migration
I'm a iOS/Android developer and I'm not too expert with servers so I don't know how to make a server migration in the least risky way.
This is my current scenario (this has been working for a long time without problems):
iOS/Android app (pro) --> mysubdomain1.domain.com --> Digital Ocean Floating IP --> Digital Ocean Droplet #1 (which has a Let’s encrypt certificate associated to mysubdomain1.domain.com).
Now I have a new droplet with much more resources, some bugs fixed, etc... This is my new scenario and it's working fine:
iOS/Android app (test) --> mysubdomain2.domain.com --> Digital Ocean Droplet #2 (which has a Let’s encrypt certificate associated to mysubdomain2.domain.com).
I would like to know the best (and least risky) way to migrate from the first scenario to the second one (I could make a backup and restore of the back-end database without problems in minutes from one droplet to the other).  I guess that this will fail:
iOS/Android app (pro) --> mysubdomain1.domain.com --> Digital Ocean Floating IP (pointing now to the new droplet) --> Digital Ocean Droplet #2
I guess this will fail because Let’s encrypt certificate in Droplet #2 is for mysubdomain2.domain.com but connection will be made through mysubdomain1.domain.com.
I was thinking on setting Droplet #2 to mysubdomain1.domain.com too before changing the Floating IP. But I guess this will fail again because Let’s encrypt won’t access Droplet #2 (because mysubdomain1.domain.com points to Droplet #1) and Droplet #2 won’t have the Let’s encrypt certificate.
I wonder if it’s possible to copy the Let’s encrypt certificates from Droplet #1 to Droplet #2 so Droplet #2 supports connections from both subdomains.
Should I do something like this?:

set my apps to maintenance mode (I can do this using Firebase functions)
turn off Droplet#1
point Floating IP (mysubdomain1.domain.com) to Droplet#2.
change Droplet#2 configuration to mysubdomain1.domain.com
Restart Droplet#2 (and its docker containers) to get this new
configuration.

I’ve read about load balancers and such things but I’m afraid it’s too deep for my server knowledge at the moment.

While the exact way to migrate depends a lot on the details, like if you can merge the data sets, how acceptable downtime is and so forth, there's some general things that can be said.

I wonder if it’s possible to copy the Let’s encrypt certificates from Droplet #1 to Droplet #2 so Droplet #2 supports connections from both subdomains.

Yes, you can - or you can issue a new cert for the same name. Certificates are after all just pieces of information stored in files, and can be copied.
I would start by reducing TTL for the name well in advance to a low value, e.g. 60 seconds. This should minimize downtime. Then, take the #1 server offline, copy data to new server, reconfigure DNS to point to the new IP, and bring up the new server.
Another way would be to have something in front that directs traffic - this may be a load balancer, or a simple reverse proxy. You could even run the reverse proxy on droplet #1 to redirect traffic while DNS is propagating to reduce downtime even further, to the time it takes to copy data.
A lot of the details are hard to tell without further knowledge of your application however.

Thank you very much vidario, I'll investigate your suggestions further.
